# How do [ H | _ ] and [ _ | T ] in predicates work?

Tags: prolog, predicate, clause

I am still learning Prolog and I came across this little snippet of code that I don't quite know if I have understood correctly.

Code:

```erlang
% Takes the spiders friends and returns a list with persons who don't know each other.
getConspirators( [], Res, Res).

getConspirators( [H|T], CConspirators, Res):-
  append( [H|T], CConspirators, PK),
  knowsAtleastOne( PK),
  % Gets all the friends of the possible conspirator H.
  allFriends( H, PFriends),
  subtract( T, PFriends, Pprim),
  getConspirators( Pprim, [H|CConspirators], Res).

getConspirators( [_|T], CConspirators, Res) :-
  getConspirators( T, CConspirators, Res).

% Checks if any person Y or Y's friends know anybody in PK.
knowsAtleastOne( PK):-
    forall( person(Y), (memberchk(Y,PK) ; friendCons(Y,PK)) ).

% Checks if a person X's friends know any of the conspirators.
friendCons( X, Conspirators):-
    friend( X, Y),
    memberchk( Y, Conspirators),
    !.
```

(this is NOT the whole program, just a small snippet of it)

I am not sure if I have understood the `getConspirators( [H|T], CConspirators, Res) :-` and the `getConspirators( [_|T], CConspirators, Res) :-` parts of the
`getConspirators` predicate. They look almost the same! Now, I do know that the "`_`" symbol means "literally any value" (AKA Prolog doesn't care about what value it is). But how does Prolog know which case to pick when running through the code? My theory is that Prolog runs the `getConspirators( [_|T], CConspirators, Res) :-` case if and only if the `getConspirators( [H|T], CConspirators, Res) :-` case fails (returns `false`) somewhere along the way. Have I understood this correctly?

Comment: No, Prolog works with backtracking, but it does this *regardless* whether the previous clause works/fails (except if you use some things like cut `!`).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Can you explain a little bit more in detail? I am a Prolog newbie :)

Comment: I think simply explaining this piece of code is hard without have some knowledge about simpler Prolog predicate. Prolog is a bit unique as a programming language: it is declarative, has builtin backtracking, predicates work multidirectional, and the mix of all these features tends to be hard to understand.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So if the `getConspirators([H|T], CConspirators, Res):-` part had a cut "!" before its recursive call (does it matter where you place it?) it would stop running the code there if something failed during runtime and jump to the next clause (`getConspirators([_|T], CConspirators, Res) :-`)? But without a cut (like here) it would "run" the last clause everytime after the first one regardless of what happens? So if all of this is correct the second clauses task is to simply jump to the next element in the list (like a for-loop)?

Comment: no, if the predicate calls inside the `getConspirators([H|T], CConspirators, Res)` clause fail before reaching the cut `!`, the cut will not be "executed". If you execute the cut, you will not consider the remaining clauses of that predicate **in that recursive call** (not globally, nor in the recursive calls that originate from that call).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So what is the actual purpose of the `getConspirators([_|T], CConspirators, Res) :-` predicate (the last one). Why is it there?

Comment: Start with **much** smaller programs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three elements in play here: backtracking, unification and the list notation. I'll explain the three with a simpler example:

```
moon(europa).
moon(ganymede).

planet(jupiter).
planet(saturn).
```

We know that Europa and Ganymede are two moons (of Jupiter) and that Jupiter and Saturn are planets. When we query what planets are known, we write:

```
?- planet(X).
X = jupiter ;  % type ; for the next answer
X = saturn.    % there's no more answer, hence .
```

Unification happens when prolog looks for a rule head which fits to the query where the variables are substituted accordingly. For instance, there is no substitution that makes `moon(X) = planet(Y)` equal, but there is one for `planet(jupiter) = planet(X)`, namely `X=jupiter`. That's how you obtain the first solution. For the second solution, Prolog needs to unifywith the second rule head, namely `planet(saturn) = planet(X)`. Because this is done after the first option is completely enumerated, we call this backtracking.

Now we can focus on (linked) lists. A list is either empty (`[]`) or it has a first element `X` prepended to a tail list `Xs` (`[X|Xs]`). Prolog has also a nicer notation for the list `[X | [Y | [] ]]`, namely `[X,Y]`. Internally they are the same. When we now want to collect a list of astral objects, we can formulate the following three rules:

```
astral_objects([]).        % The empty list is a list of astral objects.

astral_objects([X|Xs]) :-  % The list [X | Xs] is a list of astral objects if...
    moon(X),               % ... its first element X is a moon
    astral_objects(Xs).    % ... and the remaining list Xs is a list of astral objects

astral_object([X|Xs]) :-   % Likewise for planets
    planet(X),
    astral_objects(Xs).
```

When we formulate query for a two-element list, we get all combinations of objects:

```
?- astral_object([A,B]).
A = B, B = europa ;
A = europa,
B = ganymede ;
A = europa,
B = jupiter ;
A = europa,
B = saturn ;
A = ganymede,
B = europa ;
A = B, B = ganymede ;
A = ganymede,
B = jupiter
%...
```

By unification, only rules 2 and 3 apply. In both cases we have `astral_objects([X|Xs]) = astral_objects([A,B])`. Remember that `[A,B]` is shorthand for `[A|[B]]` and there for `X=A` and `Xs=[B]`. The first rule of the body will unify `X` with the corresponding moon/planet and the recursion step describes the tail. Again, we unify `astral_objects([X|Xs]) = astral_objects([B])`, leading to `X=B` and `Xs = []`. Now the recursion step will only match the terminal case of the empty list and we have fully explored this path.

Now what happens if we look for an arbitrary list of astral objects?

```
?- astral_object(Xs).
Xs = [] ;
Xs = [europa] ;
Xs = [europa, europa] ;
Xs = [europa, europa, europa] ;
Xs = [europa, europa, europa, europa] ;
Xs = [europa, europa, europa, europa, europa] 
%... does not terminate
```

The head `astral_objects(Xs)` matches all three bodies. After returning the substitution for the terminal case, it descends into the first rule over and over again. Since the length of the list is unrestricted, there are an infinite number of solutions to find before the third rule is ever tried. To avoid this, you can fairly enumerate the lists before you try to make them satisfy the predicate:

```
?- length(Xs,_), astral_object(Xs).
Xs = [] ;
Xs = [europa] ;
Xs = [ganymede] ;
Xs = [jupiter] ;
Xs = [saturn] ;
Xs = [europa, europa] ;
Xs = [europa, ganymede] ;
Xs = [europa, jupiter] ;
Xs = [europa, saturn] ;
Xs = [ganymede, europa]
%...
```

It still does not terminate, but you see the lists in ascending length and therefore the variety.

Answer (score 3):

the question asked was "the `getConspirators([H|T], CConspirators, Res) :- _body_` and the `getConspirators([_|T], CConspirators, Res) :- _body_` parts ... My theory is that Prolog runs the getConspirators([_|T], CConspirators, Res) :- case if and only if the getConspirators([H|T], CConspirators, Res) :- case fails (returns false)"

Your theory is incorrect .  Both of them will match .  The only difference is that for the case of  `getConspirators([H|T], CConspirators, Res) :- _body_` the first element of the list will be available in the *body* as variable named `H` . But for `getConspirators([_|T], CConspirators, Res) :- _body_` the first element of the list will not be available in the *body* as a named variable . 
A good way to interpret the meaning of `_` as demonstrated in this code is "a variable that I do not care to refer to later" .